# MongoDb $lookup nested document in array fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate, lookup

I have a list of document categories ： documentCategory
I have a document table
How do I put individual documents in Document into UI children in documentCategory

```js
1、I have a list of document categories ： documentCategory

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61cd249f50f3abf2e172d743"),
    "name" : "Vue3",
    "pid" : "-1",
    "level" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "UI",
            "pid" : "61cd249f50f3abf2e172d743",
            "level" : 2,
            "_id" : ObjectId("61cd27d1f3b969fec5458d89")
        }
    ]
}


2、I have a document table  
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61cd4813db3e3db388e1d7cf"),
    "name" : "ElementUI",
    "cid" : "61cd27d1f3b969fec5458d89",
    "cname" : "UI",
    "pid" : "61cd249f50f3abf2e172d743",
    "pname" : "Vue3",
}
```

Hoping to get results ：

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61cd249f50f3abf2e172d743"),
    "name" : "Vue3",
    "pid" : "-1",
    "level" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "UI",
            "pid" : "61cd249f50f3abf2e172d743",
            "_id" : ObjectId("61cd27d1f3b969fec5458d89"),  
            children:[
                {name:'ElementUI'},{name:'**'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I put individual documents in Document into UI children in documentCategory

Comment: It looks like you want to match the `category _id` with the tables `cid` correct? that is looking up from `ObjectId` to `String` and will cause problems. Or are you perhaps wanting to look up if both `pid` are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to match an ObjectId onto a string I had to add the $set stage to convert them into the same type (string).

Note that I named my 2nd collection tables instead of table since best practice is plural

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'name': 'Vue3'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$children'
    }
  }, {
    '$set': {
      'children._id': {
        '$toString': '$children._id'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'tables', 
      'localField': 'children._id', 
      'foreignField': 'cid', 
      'as': 'children.children', 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$project': {
            'name': 1, 
            '_id': 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'name': {
        '$first': '$name'
      }, 
      'pid': {
        '$first': '$pid'
      }, 
      'level': {
        '$first': '$level'
      }, 
      'children': {
        '$push': '$children'
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,     { $addFields: { childId: { $toString: '$children._id' } } }   I tried addFields, which is the better practice of the two methods? What is the function of pipeline?  
        ```
{
          $unwind: '$children'
        },
      
        { $addFields: { childId: { $toString: '$children._id' } } },
     
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'document',
            localField: 'childId',
            foreignField: 'cid',
            as: 'children.children'
          }
        },
```

Comment: When I tried to filter all the data in pipeline with $project, it didn't seem to work  

$project: {
                  name: 1,
                  children: {
                    name: 1,
                    children: {
                      _id: 1,
                      name: 1,
                      description: 1,
                      link: 1,
                      github: 1,
                      imgUrl: 1,
                      origin: 1
                    }
                  }
                }